# data persistence in prometheus agent mode

Tags: prometheus

**Problem Description:**

I read [introduction to prometheus agent](https://prometheus.io/blog/2021/11/16/agent/#:%7E:text=The%20best%20part%20about%20Prometheus%20Agent), and now I want to use this agent mode to remote write the metrics to some storage. The document indicates the prometheus agent will persists the data temporarily on the disk if the remote write endpoint is offline(it may be back online later). But I only see the lock file and wal directory when the remote endpoint failed (the scraped targets were still up).

**What I did**

- I use prometheus agent with version 2.33.3, image is quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.33.3
- I did a test where the remote write endpoint is offline while keeping the scraped targets up

**What I confuse**

- whether the prometheus agent can persist the series and samples on disk if the remote write endpoint is offline? Or it just keep the series and samples in memory ?
- how prometheus agent remotely writes the metrics that were not sent again once the remote write endpoint is back online?

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus in agent mode  persists the collected data to disk (actually, to WAL directory) until it is written to the configured remote storage. Below is the correspondimg quote from the linked blogpost about Prometheus agent mode:

> If it cannot reach the remote endpoint, it persists the data temporarily on the disk until the remote endpoint is back online. This is currently limited to a two-hour buffer only, similar to non-agent Prometheus

Note that Prometheus can persist data for only two last hours. If the remote storage is unavailable for longer periods of time, then Prometheus will lose the data older than two hours. If you need a Prometheus-compatible agent, which can persist data for more than two hours in the case of long unavailability of remote storagr, then take a look at [vmagent](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html) - the project I work on. It understands Prometheus scrape configs and can persist data if the remote storage is unavailable for more than two hours.